# iOS Xcode distribution cant upload App for review - no access

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a developer part of a team and I can't upload our app to iTunes Connect from Xcode.

Error from archive:
[image]

I have a company developer account (ocularLogic). I am part of another company as well where I have an admin role. I am uploading the app with ID 1446905085 for the client from my computer using Xcode. I have downloaded provisioning profiles and key chain access for development so why can't I upload the app????

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upload successfully. **The trick is to be added as a user to both the "Developer Account" AND "iTunes Connect".** I was part of the developer team to create profiles, ect but I was not added as a user to their iTunes Connect. I would assume they were one of the same but I guess not.